# Doubt with the deduction of the law of sines

Tags: trigonometry

I was reading in a book the deduction of the sinus law.
The book uses an image similar to this:

[image: Sinus law]

The steps to arrive the sinus law are:


$
\sin \alpha =  \frac{z}{c}
$

$
\sin  \beta  =  \frac{y}{c} 
$

Then as c is equal in both equations:

$
 \frac{z}{\sin \alpha }  =  \frac{y}{\sin \beta } 
$


Then we can see in the image:


$
\sin( \pi -  \gamma) =  \frac{z}{a} 
$

$
\sin( \pi -  \gamma) =  \frac{y}{b} 
$

As $z/a = y/b$, if we multiply by $a/z$ the left part of the 2º equation, and by $b/y$ the right part we arrive to:

$
\frac{a}{\sin \alpha } =  \frac{b}{\sin \beta}
$


The question is how arrive to: 


$
\frac{a}{\sin \alpha } =  \frac{b}{\sin \beta} = \frac{c}{\sin  \gamma }
$

The book say that we can arrive using the pair of angles alpha/gamma or beta/gamma but I don't know how to do it.
Finally other related question, why in the image:
$
\cos( \pi - \gamma) = -\cos \gamma
$


Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry. You can do the same dance with e.g $a$ with $\alpha$ and $c$ with $\gamma$ to deduce the missing equality.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand it... Can explain a little your answer?. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the related question:

[image]

We can also use the formula for the cosine of a difference
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(\pi-\gamma)
&=\overbrace{\cos(\pi)}^{-1}\cos(\gamma)+\overbrace{\sin(\pi)}^0\sin(\gamma)\\
&=-\cos(\gamma)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You have solved my related question, thanks!